# run a binary that uses ncurses in eshell under xterm-256color emulation

Tags: eshell, rust

I have a binary (a rust program that uses bindings to ncurses) and I need to run it in eshell as xterm-256color (well, make it work correctly at least). I haven't figured out how to do this yet. Tried setting TERM to xterm-256color, but that didn't seem to help. Is there even a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `M-x term` instead of eshell? To my knowledge `eshell` does not support ncurses anyway.

Comment: I did not, I asked the question about eshell, because that's what I need.

Comment: It would be helpfull if you explain why that is. You can tell eshell to run certain commands in `term` by adding them to `eshell-visual-commands` (`(add-to-list 'eshell-visual-commands "htop")`), so from the users point of view it'll be seamless.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I saw in official documentation, section 4.1 [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Input_002fOutput.html) and that's what didn't work for me, so I turned to this group for help. Seems like there's either deeper knowledge (more likely) about this or this is not possible (hardly so).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the program is working wrong? Is the output completely carbage, or is it just colors, input or screen width/height that's wrong? Does the program give an error message? Do you have the source code for the program, and the ability to make changes to it? I tried my own program that is written in Rust using ncurses inside `term`, and that did work. I imagine that either the problem is caused by the program you're trying to run, or you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: The program (accessible to modification) does run inside `term` with certain artifacts (some garbled characters, no color) but fails from eshell with correctly set `eshell-visual-commands` value.

Comment: Here's the error message that I captured to buffer (otherwise the screen just blinks and returns the input): `Error opening terminal: unknown.`

Comment: Is the program source code publicly available somewhere? If not, can you try to find the part where that error code originates and see what causes it. If it checks for $TERM, try adding an exception for "dumb" (since that's what eshell uses) or "eterm-color" (which is what term seems to use). Make sure that your eshell/term also uses those same values.

Comment: Yes the code is [here](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs), however I should mention that I'm on OS X, so there might be some extra quirks. Just compile and run any of the examples.

Comment: I tested the example 4, which did start and run properly, except that the F1 key doesn't work. I think emacs `term` doesn't support the extended keypad (`ncurses::keypad()`), which means that you can only run rather simple programs in it (ones that don't make use of F-keys or control and such). I don't get that error myself, but I tracked it down to libncurses itself. It seems like it thinks you don't have TERM set at all. Can you try running `echo $TERM` on both `eshell` and `term`

Comment: term: `eterm-color`, eshell returns nothing, seems the value is not set

Comment: Try adding `(setenv "TERM" "xterm")` to your .emacs

Comment: Did that. Tried running ex_1 from eshell, but the result was the same. Here's the output from the buffer I captured `[?1049h[1;47r(B[m[4l[?7h[H[2JHello, world!
[47;1H[?1049l
[?1l>`. Without redirection of output to buffer the screen just blinks and goes back to input.

Comment: That output does look like it's not being executed as a visual command. Are you sure the `eshell-visual-commands` is correct (just the executable name without path, no typos)? If that is correct, then I can't really think of anything else right now.

Comment: here's the value of `eshell-visual-commands` `("vi" "screen" "top" "less" "more" "lynx" "ncftp" "pine" "tin" "trn" "elm" "ex_1" "ex_2" "ex_3" "ex_4" "ex_5" "ex_6")`

Comment: Could this be a bug?